# How is inapproximability by polynomial size circuits sufficient for the Nisan-Wigderson generator?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, derandomization, pseudorandom-generators

I couldn't understand how exactly Yao's XOR lemma was used to prove the following claim made in the proof of Theorem 2 of the [original paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272574/1-s2.0-S0022000005X80436/1-s2.0-S0022000005800431/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIGQNuORB98ZsUDZWDA9uabTiX0FcsSa89036wYK%2BVO%2FAAiAuBjAExobCniGvvT8Y4UDZXpYEZQDnRQ6%2BG01w6OwNfiq6BQiZ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIM8sgqZdWNZaIJOxauKo4FItzT0WRw5KVBbi7g5FEFWWsWb44yLzBPgSo%2BpffD8b%2Fzy1aF%2FPL%2FJmCcH%2BCGkIccgWdCuJa%2BTSlmrE6GYdREeQ3fvRDWpOYxO2rZb3vCw1yycXGYhvQYUxQ4GGqf%2Bbr2EVcEP3lc72S%2FaN8pt%2BF%2BWl7clmMyLRw6LsI%2BT5Ra20paEhOIBlsYQhgCWph2dUWwHc29BVXaQHWoGzqJmfqe0TBuLq9UY%2FDcxXHesMJRIP6JzWH3dnt%2BCtOSE5rT2H0aXh9K2NxeutjKvRMeLGcXoM%2BuKyg1gOeQ6AHA8%2FzThp6rgyyU0hOzcEuPRjJsnAa4jnTJOKzmnrR6tQRuU0ANZcEtGJ2M%2Fq7lGRwdx5%2B2EoMNvvMp1ba6JrRBRtWU264q79sgGr2RukIEN28j01QeQ1yWorSVxjrLU7P91wMIzjpOvsu3krrP4nu%2Fag2F%2FQ4F0F%2FortqcM8Erge4MrVKLkvxIbR9FviLLN2nGgImx6qYFN47Izb0wEDTn0y8HuLM2TLUFTj%2BDlnlQArih632z8FqZ0wxRrpy86e%2BmaNI%2Fr5ACsyMsy5jgl9Shg73ZxnTGAPIPVsc43TZ0g6AxfKiXh1bch6%2BaZpu7TGL1yw%2FAxoWJv2qK%2BGp3iALSj95UedxRPHkemT1x9u5YNC5FQGnLzUElHtC7wEmSO83zTk%2FSsGV0XAnJPk6lM3CVlhqeEhMwP%2B487%2FOemFZDojnh5B0RRieVKpbjgFJ9D41WPYeFYrTNn0HZEyAyxdKSKfbCq%2FCsNi%2FFPTfWetZouYdH9Z%2BpISvcE%2BE4FguMsx5SEXAzVrDrmRWFUUW4Uinw22F%2BBV0QuGFZenuP8K6gZbzwnYT1wAmF22xguZnuMHbyh%2FufMJDY%2F58GOrIBoyPT6K0B7NYdNLpiZbFaZQulX0HUu%2Fx2YPZhVK30Pu655%2BaQHfddW2P%2BYundeQU%2BVqlu7Pb4unNgMkVAKFHBcpGa0LnZbOtDXAoh3ZGHy98mJJCHILcGEvOD%2BMWyH8sStDqBsYozqMY1jKyV2Nn%2FawjX%2BZh%2FH%2FcybuyVWVpy1IUwp45EZ8bUDDxCtIDc%2BgL6kxzef2WY0fpZOwyjrt4j%2FcWT3HlvsXcEKcF%2BpcVxlMQ4og%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230302T004042Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSUKYK2HF%2F20230302%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=a610c30313536dfb251f8825df2308aa8ac4e8c4eab1e3b1dddf23fe6db6e792&hash=e5f5a3bd5e59e25b31833445ac9e43d5ff079efdc1802136bbc2a236884905c8&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022000005800431&tid=spdf-fdf52c3d-201b-4017-b23e-9d0b37a62395&sid=351800cc7375b447007a4dd83ed98446b2d4gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=13105801555b5b57575f&rr=7a1597014ea79698&cc=us) describing the Nisan-Wigderson generator, so I decided to do it explicitly myself.

**Claim 1**: If $f \in EXP$ cannot be approximated by circuits of polynomial size, then for every $0 < \rho < 1$, there is a quick pseudorandom generator $G : n^\rho \rightarrow n$.

In the paper, we say that a function $f : \{0, 1\}^m \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ cannot be approximated by circuits of size $s : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ if there exists constant $k_0$ such that for every s-size circuit family ${C_m}$, we have

$$\Pr(C_m(x) \neq f(x)) > \frac{1}{m^{k_0}}$$.

As such, we may rewrite Claim 1 equivalently as follows.

**Alternative Claim 1** Suppose there exists $f \in EXP$ such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists constant $k_0$ (which depends on $k$; we denote this by writing $k_0 := k_0(k)$) such that for all $m^k$-size circuit families ${C(m)}$, $\Pr(C_m(x) \neq f(x)) > \frac{1}{m^{k_0(k)}}$. Then for every $0 < \rho < 1$, there is a quick pseudorandom generator $G : n^\rho \rightarrow n$.

The particular version of Yao's XOR Lemma which I use is Levin's version (Lemma 2 [here](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/COL/yao.pdf)). In the interest of self-containment I recite the relevant statement here as follows. Note that this version is stated in terms of $\{-1, 1\}$ valued functions, but we can simply reinterpret $f$ in the hypothesis of Claim 1 as $(-1)^f$.

**Yao's Lemma:** Let $f : \{0, 1\}^m \rightarrow \{-1, 1\}$, $s : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, $\{C_m\}$ be any circuit family of size at most $s$, and $\delta(m)$ be an upper bound on the correlation $\underset{x\in\{0,1\}^m}{\mathbb{E}}[C_m(x) \cdot f(x)]$ between $C_m$ and $f$ such that $|\delta(m)|$ is bounded away from 1 (i.e. $|\delta(m)| \leq 1 - 1/\omega(1)$).
Then for any $t : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let $m' := t(m) \cdot m$ and we have that $\delta^{(t)}(m) := \left( \delta(m) \right)^{t(m)} + \epsilon(m)$ is a bound on the correlation between $f^{(t)} : \{0,1\}^{m'} \rightarrow \{-1, 1\}$ such that $f^{(t)}(x_1x_2...x_{t(m)}) := \prod_{i = 1}^{t(m)}f(x_i)$ (here each $x_i \in \{0, 1\}^m$) and any circuit on $m'$ bits of size at most $s'(m') := (\frac{\epsilon(m)}{m})^{O(1)}s(m) + (m')^{O(1)}$.

After going through the paper, it seems that proving that the Nisan-Wigderson construction for a generator is indeed a quick pseudorandom generator boils down to a constraint satisfaction problem over 4 variables parameterized by the output length $n$ of the generator: $m := m(n)$, the input length of the function $f$ in the hypothesis of Claim 1; $t(m)$, the number of times we XOR $f$ with itself to create the hardness-amplified $f^{(t)}$ in Yao's lemma; $\epsilon(m)$ as in Yao's lemma; and $k$ as in the alternative statement of Claim 1 above (note that here $m^k$ is $s(m)$ in Yao's lemma). The constraints we must satisfy are as follows.

(1) $2^{O(m(n))} \cdot t(m(n)) \cdot n = 2^{O(n^\rho)}$

This constraint comes from the requirement that our generator needs to be *quick*. A generator G : $n^{l(n)} \rightarrow n$ is called quick if the generator runs in time $2^{O(l(n))}$, and here $l(n) = n^\rho$. To see that the left hand side of this constraint bounds the run time of the Nisan-Wigderson generator, note that the Nisan-Wigderson generator outputs the concatenation of $n$ calls to $f^{(t)}$, where each call of $f^{(t)}$ takes the XOR of $t(m(n))$ evaluations of $f \in EXP$.

(2) $n \geq m'(n) = \Omega(n^\frac{\rho}{2})$, where recall $m'(n) := t(m(n)) \cdot m(n)$ is the input length of the hardness-amplified function $f^{(t)}$.

This requirement ensures that there exists a $(\log(n), m'(n))$-design by Lemma 2.5 in the paper. The existence of such a design is a prerequisite for the proof that the NW Generator is indeed pseudorandom (Lemma 2.4 in the paper).

(3) $\delta^{(t)}(m(n)) \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$

(4) $s'(m'(n)) \geq n^2$

Constraints (3) and (4) above come from the fact that the Nisan-Wigderson generator requires that its basis function ($f^{(t)}$ here) has hardness at least $n^2$ for it to be pseudorandom (again, see Lemma 2.4 in the paper), or in other words, that for all circuits ${C_{m'}}$ (here $m' := m'(n)$) of size at most $n^2$, we have $|\Pr(C_{m'}(x) = f^{(t)}(x)) - \frac{1}{2}| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Constraints (3) and (4) guarantee that we amplify the hardness of $f$ in Yao's lemma enough to satisfy this requirement.

---

**My Question**: How is the assumption that $f \in EXP$ cannot be approximated by polynomial size circuits sufficient to guarantee that both constraints (3) and (4) above are satisfied?

I will elaborate my question as follows. Expanding constraint (4) gives

$s'(m'(n)) := (\frac{\epsilon(m(n))}{m(n)})^{O(1)}(m(n))^k - (t(m(n)) \cdot m(n))^{O(1)} > n^2$

Note that in order to satisfy (4), an obviously necessary condition is that $(m(n))^k > t(m(n))$ for all sufficiently large $n$. In other words, it must be that

(5) $$t(m(n)) = O((m(n)^k)$$

otherwise it is impossible for us to choose $k$ large enough for (4) to hold. We now exhibit an asymptotic lower bound on $t(m)$. Since $1 - x \geq e^{-\frac{x}{1 - x}}$ for all $x < 1$, we have that

$$(\delta(m(n)))^{t(m(n))} = (1 - \frac{2}{(m(n))^{k_0}})^{t(m(n))} \geq \exp\left(-\frac{\frac{2t(m(n))}{(m(n))^{k_0}}}{1 - \frac{2}{(m(n))^{k_0}}}\right)$$

and thus a necessary condition for condition (3) to hold (where we let $m := m(n)$) is that

$$ \exp\left(-\frac{\frac{2t(m)}{m^{k_0}}}{1 - \frac{2}{m^{k_0}}}\right) < \frac{2}{n^2} $$

from which we obtain:

$$-\frac{\frac{2t(m)}{m^{k_0}}}{1 - \frac{2}{m^{k_0}}} < \ln(\frac{2}{n^2})$$

Rearranging gives,

$$\frac{\frac{t(m)}{m^{k_0}}}{1 - \frac{2}{m^{k_0}}} > \ln(n) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$$

implying,

$${\frac{t(m)}{m^{k_0}}} = \Omega(\ln(n))$$

which necessitates

(6) $$t(m) = \Omega(m^{k_0})$$

Together, (5) and (6) tell us in order for the desired hardness amplification to be possible it must be that $k \geq k_0$. However, recall that $k_0 := k_0(k)$ depends crucially on our choice of $k$. As I understand it, the hypothesis of claim 1 provides no guarantee that $k_0$ is at most $k$. For all we know it could always be that for any choice of $k$ we make, it is always the case that $k_0 > k$. So how is the hypothesis of Claim 1 sufficient to prove that the Nisan-Wigderson generator is indeed pseudorandom?